# Choose folder for download from pytube? In webapp

Tags: flask, directory, download, pytube, render.com

In Flask webapp i need to specify folder for download video from pytube.
Works with tkinter in project, but not when i deployed webapp to render.com.

It gives me Error 500 in deployed webapp.

```
root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        root.attributes("-topmost", True)
        self.directory = tk.filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root)
```

```
[2023-09-04 08:49:04,246] ERROR in app: Exception on /download [POST]
```

Sep 4 10:49:04 AM  Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 4 10:49:04 AM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2529, in wsgi_app

Sep 4 10:49:04 AM      response = self.full_dispatch_request()

Sep 4 10:49:04 AM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request

Sep 4 10:49:04 AM      rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
Sep 4 10:49:04 AM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request

Sep 4 10:49:04 AM      rv = self.dispatch_request()
Sep 4 10:49:04 AM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request

Sep 4 10:49:04 AM      return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
Sep 4 10:49:04 AM    File "/opt/render/project/src/website/downloader.py", line 37, in download

Sep 4 10:49:04 AM      video = DownloadVideo().download(url)
Sep 4 10:49:04 AM    File "/opt/render/project/src/website/downloader.py", line 92, in **init**

Sep 4 10:49:04 AM      root = tk.Tk()
Sep 4 10:49:04 AM    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line 2023, in **init**

Sep 4 10:49:04 AM      self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
Sep 4 10:49:04 AM  _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Sep 4 10:49:04 AM  127.0.0.1 - - [04/Sep/2023:08:49:04 +0000] "POST /download HTTP/1.1" 500 265 "https://vojjtak.onrender.com/downloader" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

Comment: Can you edit your post and include the traceback?

Comment: Yes there it is.